# SQL question about combining different counts in a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm just starting a database project for my institute in Oracle SQL Developer and I'm having problems with the first query in which I have to return "name of building", "total number of departments", "number of departments with 1 room", "number of departments with 2 rooms", and so on until 5 rooms.

So far I have this:

```
    select  E.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO as "NOMBRE EDIFICIO",
            count(D.NRO_DEPARTAMENTO) as "TOTAL DEPTOS",
            (
             select count(D.NRO_DEPARTAMENTO) as "TOTAL DEPTOS 1 DORMITORIO"
             from (edificio E join departamento D 
             on E.id_edificio = D.ID_EDIFICIO)
             where D.TOTAL_DORMITORIOS = 1
             group by E.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO
            ) AS "DEPTOS 1 DORM"        
    from (edificio E join departamento D on E.id_edificio = D.ID_EDIFICIO)
    group by E.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO
    order BY E.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO;
```

Problem is, I'm getting the first 2 columns well, but the subquery I'm using to get the total number of departments with 1 room, is throwing me a 01427 error because (I think) I'm putting a multiple row subquery in the SELECT clause.

I don't know how to approach to the right query if it's not using a subquery in the Select clause. I would be very grateful if any of you could help me. Thanks in advance.

This is my 2nd semester in programming classes so I don't know pretty much anything. In fact, I just read "Combining results of different count(*) sql queries" question and answer, and I'm not understanding.

Comment: If your question is solved by the given answer, please accept the answer as correct, or, if you found your own answer, please add the answer yourself and accept it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this way:

```
SELECT  E.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO as "NOMBRE EDIFICIO",
         (
         SELECT COUNT(D.NRO_DEPARTAMENTO)         
         FROM departamento D 
         WHERE E.id_edificio = D.ID_EDIFICIO
         ) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS",
         (
          SELECT COUNT(D.NRO_DEPARTAMENTO) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 1 DORMITORIO"
          FROM departamento D
          WHERE D.TOTAL_DORMITORIOS = 1
          AND D.id_edificio = E.id_edificio
         ) AS "DEPTOS 1 DORM",
         (
          SELECT COUNT(D.NRO_DEPARTAMENTO)
          AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 1 DORMITORIO"
          FROM departamento D
          WHERE D.TOTAL_DORMITORIOS = 2
          AND D.id_edificio = E.id_edificio
         ) AS "DEPTOS 2 DORM",
         (
          SELECT COUNT(D.NRO_DEPARTAMENTO)
          AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 1 DORMITORIO"
          FROM departamento D
          WHERE D.TOTAL_DORMITORIOS = 3
          AND D.id_edificio = E.id_edificio
         ) AS "DEPTOS 3 DORM",
         (
          SELECT COUNT(D.NRO_DEPARTAMENTO)
          AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 1 DORMITORIO"
          FROM departamento D
          WHERE D.TOTAL_DORMITORIOS = 4
          AND D.id_edificio = E.id_edificio
         ) AS "DEPTOS 4 DORM",
         (
          SELECT COUNT(D.NRO_DEPARTAMENTO)
          AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 1 DORMITORIO"
          FROM departamento D
          WHERE D.TOTAL_DORMITORIOS = 5
          AND D.id_edificio = E.id_edificio
         ) AS "DEPTOS 5 DORM"
FROM EDIFICIO E
ORDER BY E.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing the sub query with:

```
Sum(Case when D.TOTAL_DORMITORIOS = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as "DEPTOS 1 DORM"
```

... And so on

```
Sum(Case when D.TOTAL_DORMITORIOS = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as "DEPTOS 2 DORM"
Sum(Case when D.TOTAL_DORMITORIOS = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as "DEPTOS 3 DORM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer may be more peformant if you first of all group the results from the departamento table, since then you'll be querying the table once, instead of 6 times per id_edificio, like so:

```
SELECT e.edi_nombre_edificio AS "NOMBRE EDIFICIO",
       d.total_deptos AS "TOTAL DEPTOS",
       d.deptos_1_dorm AS "DEPTOS 1 DORM",
       d.deptos_2_dorm AS "DEPTOS 2 DORM",
       d.deptos_3_dorm AS "DEPTOS 3 DORM",
       d.deptos_4_dorm AS "DEPTOS 4 DORM",
       d.deptos_5_dorm AS "DEPTOS 5 DORM"
FROM   edificio e
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id_edificio,
                          COUNT(nro_departamento) total_deptos,
                          COUNT(CASE WHEN total_dormitorios = 1 THEN nro_departamento END) deptos_1_dorm,
                          COUNT(CASE WHEN total_dormitorios = 1 THEN nro_departamento END) deptos_2_dorm,
                          COUNT(CASE WHEN total_dormitorios = 1 THEN nro_departamento END) deptos_3_dorm,
                          COUNT(CASE WHEN total_dormitorios = 1 THEN nro_departamento END) deptos_4_dorm,
                          COUNT(CASE WHEN total_dormitorios = 1 THEN nro_departamento END) deptos_5_dorm
                   FROM   departamento) d ON e.id_edificio = d.id_edificio;
```